# My code for adding duplicates in polynomial is not working(Program was to multiply two polynomials using linked list)

Tags: c++, linked-list

code of multiplying two polys and it's giving right output till here:

```
void mResultpoly(Poly **second, Poly **head, Poly *current)
{
    Poly *t1 = *second;

    while (t1 != NULL)
    {
        Poly *new_node = new Poly;
        new_node->data = (t1->data) * (current->data);
        new_node->expo = t1->expo + current->expo;
        new_node->next = *head;
        *head = new_node;
        t1 = t1->next;
    }
}

void multiply(Poly **head1, Poly **head2)
{
    Poly *second;

    Poly *t1, *t2;
    t1 = *head1;
    t2 = *head2;

    while (t1 != NULL)
    {
        mResultpoly(&t2, &second, t1);
        t1 = t1->next;
    }

    addDuplicates(&second);
    cout << "Multiplication result of two polynomials is: ";
    display(second);
}
```

Code for adding duplicates:

```
void addDuplicates(Poly **start)
{

    Poly *t3 = *start;
    Poly *t4, *dup;

    while (t3 != NULL && t3->next != NULL)
    {
        cout << "hjfjh" << endl;
        t4 = t3;

        while (t4->next != NULL)
        {
            cout << "Here: " << t4->data << " " << t3->data << " " << endl;
            if (t3->expo == t4->next->expo)
            {
                t3->data = t3->data + t4->next->data;
                dup = t4->next;
                t4->next = t4->next->next;
                delete (dup);

                cout << "Here inside: " << t4->data << " " << t3->data << " " << endl;
            }
            else
            {

                t4 = t4->next;
            }
        }
        t3 = t3->next;
    }
}
```

Here I had put a print satement showing it's only running one time w.r.t the outer while loop

1x0 + 2x1 + 3x2 + 2x1 + 4x2 + 6x3 + 3x2 + 6x3 + 9x4: This is the output I'm getting having two polynomials, 3x^2 + 2x+ 1(both are same);

and the print statement I have put inside loop to check is giving:
Here: 1 1
Here: 2 1
Here: 3 1
Here: 2 1
Here: 4 1
Here: 6 1
Here: 3 1
Here: 6 1
Here: 9 1

One more little problem: If I put display(second) before addDuplicates(&second) I can't see these print statements which I find weird too.

Answer (score 0):

Please tell me if I should delete this question.

I spent 2-3 hours looking for a bug but couldn't find it. That's why I posted it here.

Bug is:
In multiply() function initialize second to NULL because while making a new list you should do that otherwise inside while loops the NULL will never be found :)